# Entity Framework - Select single record ordered by a property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table and one of the properties of the table is `TotalDue`.I wish to first order it by `TotalDue` and then select the "top" record which in this case would be the record with the highest value.

```
    homeVM.LastSaleAmount  = (from i in salesService.GetSalesOrderHeaders()
                                  .OrderByDescending(a => a.TotalDue).First();
```

This is what I've tried so far but I think `.First()` needs a parameter and I think I need a select as well but not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing method syntax and query syntax, and your use of query syntax isn't  necessary and making this harder.  Just remove it:

```
homeVM.LastSaleAmount = salesService.GetSalesOrderHeaders()
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.TotalDue)
    .Select(a => a.TotalDue)
    .First();
```

Comment: Do you know how I could possibly cast that to a decimal type? LastSaleAmount is a decimal type. I tried casting but that did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with Take method, is like top, but in Linq world.

```
homeVM.LastSaleAmount = salesService.GetSalesOrderHeaders().OrderByDescending(a => a.TotalDue).Take(1);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Okay thanks. However now I get "A query body must end with a select or query clause"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put an entire entity into `LastSaleAmount`.  use `.Select(a => a.TotalDue)` like:

```
homeVM.LastSaleAmount  = salesService.GetSalesOrderHeaders()
                              .OrderByDescending(a => a.TotalDue).Select(a => a.TotalDue).First();
```